# TypeError: Cannot set property '10' of undefined with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

i want to concatenate data.id with company.action.actions but it gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '10' of undefined
```

heres my code:

```
 company.action={};
    company.getOptions=function(){
      //  company.action={};
      //  var toto;
        //company.action.actions15=true;
        for(var i=0;i<company.selectedActionsForCompany.length;i++){
           var data=company.selectedActionsForCompany[i];
            company.action.actions[data.id]=true;

        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(company.action));
    }
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: This question needs more information.  Can you add the data structures of company?

Comment: var company = this;

Comment: company is like the scope..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have **actions** property in **company.action**

did you mean to do something like this:

```
 company.action={};
company.getOptions=function(){
  //  company.action={};
  //  var toto;
    //company.action.actions15=true;
    for(var i=0;i<company.selectedActionsForCompany.length;i++){
       var data=company.selectedActionsForCompany[i];
        company.action['actions'+data.id] = true;

    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(company.action));
}
```

?

Comment: but i want the final object like this :{"actions11":true}

Comment: Sorry i didnt understand you, i edited my answer, check it now